# How to find the range for a given number, interval and start value?

Tags: math, algebra

Provided the below values

1. start value = 1
2. End Value = 20
3. Interval = 5

I have been provided a number 6. I have to find the range of numbers in which the number 6 falls say now the answer is 6-10.

If the given number is greater than  the end value then return the same number.

Is there any formula so that i can generate the range for the number?

***UPDATE***

I tried the below solution, But it is not working if the range interval is changed,

```
 $end_value = $start_value + $range_interval;

// we blindly return the last term if value is greater than max value
if ($input_num > $end_value) {
  return '>' . $end_value;
}

// we also find if its a first value
if ($input_num <= $end_value && $value >= $start_value) {
  return $start_value . '-' . $end_value;
}

// logic to find the range for a given integer
$dived_value = $input_num/$end_value;

// round the value to get the exact match
$rounded_value = ceil($dived_value);

$upper_bound_range = $rounded_value*$end_value;

$lower_bound_range = $upper_bound_range - $end_value;

return $lower_bound_range . '-'. $upper_bound_range;
```

Comment: This question should be asked on [Math](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: if start value is 0 is included, won't range be 5-9?

Comment: @Vladimir I have updated my question with my try

Comment: @Milind Thanks for the point i changed the start value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In (c-style) pseudocode:

```
// Integer division assumed
rangeNumber = (yourNumber - startValue) / rangeLength;
lower_bound_range = startValue + rangeNumber*rangeLength;
upper_bound_range = lower_bound_range + rangeLength-1;
```

For your input:

```
rangeNumber = (6-1)/5 = 1
lower_bound_range = 1 + 5*1 = 6
upper_bound_range = 10
```

and so range is [6, 10]

Comment: But it does not work for other values, like 
startValue:100 ,Interval (rangeLength): 100,EndValue: 500

rangeNumber = (220 - 100) / 100 =  1.2
lower_bound_range = 100 + (1.2 * 100) = 220
upper_bound_range = 220 + (100-1) = 319;

Comment: @DineshKumar, sorry I assumed language uses integer division by default (as c for example), so  (220 - 100) / 100 = 1. Check how to perform integer division in the language you use

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on whether you talk about integers or floats. Since all your example numbers are integers, I assume you talk about those. I further assume that all your intervals contain the same number of integers, in your example 5, namely 1...5, 6...10, 11...15, and 16...20. Note that 0 is not contained in the 1st interval (otherwise the 1st interval had 6 numbers).
In this case the answer is easy.
Let be:
s the start value that is not contained in the 1st interval,
i the interval size, i.e. the number of integers that it contains,
p the provided number to which an interval should be assigned,
b the 1st integer in this interval, and
e the last integer in this interval.
Then:
    b = s + (p-s-1)\i * i + 1   (here, "\" means integer division, i.e. without remainder)
    e = b + i - 1
In your example:
    s = 0, i = 5, p = 6, thus
    b = 0 + (6-0-1)\5 * 5 + 1 = 6
    e = 6 + 5 - 1 = 10